# PHP Google Analytics4 admin: SERVICE_DISABLED/PERMISSION_DENIED/Google Analytics Admin API has not been used in project

Tags: php, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I get an exception that lists all these issues (reason, status, message) when trying to access a simple function in GA4 admin. First, I redirect like this:

```
 https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&access_type=offline&client_id=<CLIENT ID>&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fedit.ihousestg.com%2Foauth2callback&state=host%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fwebhosts.ihousestg.com%2F-%2FControlGoogleAnalytics%2Foauth2callback&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fanalytics.edit%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fanalytics.readonly%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fanalytics.manage.users&approval_prompt=force&include_granted_scopes=true&login_hint=andy.ihouseweb%40gmail.com
```

I get my callback with a code. I create a Google\Client:

```
$this->google_client = new Google\Client();
$this->google_client->setApplicationName('GA4 Admin beta Oauth2');
$this->google_client->setAuthConfig($OauthKeyfile);

$this->google_client->addScope(GoogleAnalyticsAdmin::ANALYTICS_EDIT);
$this->google_client->addScope(GoogleAnalyticsAdmin::ANALYTICS_READONLY);
$this->google_client->addScope(Oauth2::USERINFO_EMAIL);
$this->google_client->addScope(Analytics::ANALYTICS_MANAGE_USERS);

$this->google_client->setAccessType('offline');
$this->google_client->setApprovalPrompt("force");
$this->google_client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);

$this->google_client->setRedirectUri('https://<MY SERVER>/oauth2callback');
```

And get an access token from the code I got in the callback:

```
$this->google_client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($code);
```

And get a analytics client:

```
$this->google_analytics_service_client = new AnalyticsAdminServiceClient();
```

And then try to get the account summaries:

```
    try
    {
        // make the API call.
        Log::Debug("Calling service_client->listAccountSummaries");
        $results = $analytics_service_client->listAccountSummaries();
        return $results;
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        Log::error("There was an Exception: " . $e->Message() );
        throw $e;
    }
    finally
    {
        $analytics_service_client->close();
    }
```

Which throws the exception:

```
Google\ApiCore\ApiException: {
    "reason": "SERVICE_DISABLED",
    "domain": "googleapis.com",
    "errorInfoMetadata": {
        "service": "analyticsadmin.googleapis.com",
        "consumer": "projects\/WEIRD_PROJECT_ID"
    },
    "message": "Google Analytics Admin API has not been used in project WEIRD_PROJECT_ID before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https:\/\/console.developers.google.com\/apis\/api\/analyticsadmin.googleapis.com\/overview?project=WEIRD_PROJECT_ID then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "code": 7,
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
        {
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com\/google.rpc.Help",
            "links": [
                {
                    "description": "Google developers console API activation",
                    "url": "https:\/\/console.developers.google.com\/apis\/api\/analyticsadmin.googleapis.com\/overview?project=WEIRD_PROJECT_ID"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com\/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
            "reason": "SERVICE_DISABLED",
            "domain": "googleapis.com",
            "metadata": {
                "service": "analyticsadmin.googleapis.com",
                "consumer": "projects\/WEIRD_PROJECT_ID"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Note:

1. this is all working in my development environment, I have moved up to our stage testing environment, and am running into this. The project has these APIs enabled, per the console:

   Google Analytics Admin API
   Google Analytics API
   Google Analytics Data API

I have created a new Google account under that project (as far as I can tell), and that is what I choose when the redirect brings up the permissions page.

2. This question is a replacement for one I previously posted and have deleted, this one being more complete and up-to-date with my progress.
3. We are using the alpha code for the API, any timeline on when the beta will encompass more functionality, or even more important, when the "real" code will be out, since we are to be using GA4 in a few months?
4. My $OathKeyFile looks like:

   {"web":
   {"client_id":"MYCLIENTID.apps.googleusercontent.com",
   "project_id":"stage-1082",
   "auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
   "token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
   "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
   "client_secret":MY_CLIENT_SECRET,
   "redirect_uris":["https://edit.ihousestg.com/oauth2callback"],
   "javascript_origins":["https://edit.ihousestg.com",
   "https://www.ihousestg.com",
   "https://ihousestg.com"]
   }
   }

Comment: Did you go to the URL suggested: "Enable it by visiting https:\/\/console.developers.google.com\/apis\/api\/analyticsadmin.googleapis.com\/overview?project=WEIRD_PROJECT_ID then retry." I got the same error and enabling the API via this URL worked for me. I actually missed this instruction the first few times due to the length of the non-wrapping message.

Comment: Yeah. that didn't work because I didn't have authorization for that project. It turns out that it was a Service Account that someone else created that I didn't have access to.  Once that got straightened out, all was well.